# Text Translator API keys expiring

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I recently migrated the old Microsoft Translator API to the new Azure portal APIs and created one Text Translator API resource with Pay-As-You-Go subscription and S1 pricing tier. I created the 2 keys and both were working fine last Friday (01/27) but now I get a lot of errors and messages. One of them says: *Reason - The key used is expired.*

So, some questions about that:

1. Where do I see the expiration date of my keys?
2. How can I get keys that don't expire or autoregenerate?
3. [Bonus question] What's the difference between KEY 1 and KEY2 (I see both work the same)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were authentication issues occurring that have since been resolved.

1 & 2  Keys do not expire on a pay as you go plan.

3. There actually is no difference between key 1 & 2, they both will pull from the same allowance/quota.  One can be used as a backup.